# Create new column by using a list comprehension with two 'for' loops in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['aaaa', 'aabb', 'bbcc', 'ccdd'], 
   'col2': ['ab12', 'cd15', 'kf25', 'zx78']})
df
    col1    col2
0   aaaa    ab12
1   aabb    cd15
2   bbcc    kf25
3   ccdd    zx78
```

I want to create 'col3' based on 'col1' and 'col2', I want to get:

```py
df
    col1    col2    col3
0   aaaa    ab12    aa-12
1   aabb    cd15    aa-15
2   bbcc    kf25    bb-25
3   ccdd    zx78    cc-78
```

I tried to use list comprehension but I got the error: `ValueError: Length of values (16) does not match length of index (4)`

The code I used is :

```py
df['col3']=[x[0:2]+'-'+y[2:4] for x in df['col1'] for y in df['col2']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple slicing with the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor, and concatenation:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].str[:2] + '-' + df['col2'].str[2:4]
```

Or, if you want the last two characters of col2:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].str[:2] + '-' + df['col2'].str[-2:]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2   col3
0  aaaa  ab12  aa-12
1  aabb  cd15  aa-15
2  bbcc  kf25  bb-25
3  ccdd  zx78  cc-78
```

##### why your approach did not work

You would have needed to `zip`:

```
df['col3'] = [x[0:2]+'-'+y[2:4] for x,y in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM that's what I initially posted, but then I thought I'd stick to OP's original slicing (I don't know how the data generalizes). I'll add it as note